# Sharing multiple printers/scanners with desktop/laptop within small office

Tags: windows-7, networking, printer

I have a small office setup with 3 desktops(windows 7). I connect to the  building/facility's shared network using  Ethernet port in the wall.

I need to make my 2 printers (Ethernet, USB connectivity) and a scanner available to all my computers (without having to switch manually using multiple 'USB selector switch' currently).

I've been looking into getting either a switch or a router  and connecting all network enabled printers to it. If I connect to a switch, would my printers be visible to entire network? How do I limit access to my wired/wireless network printers for just my users, and restrict others on shared network, without having to setup private subnet?

Any insight into this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few clarifications you may need to make.

1. Do the printers and scanners have a networking ability? Are they WiFi only?
2. Something else to consider is using a workstation as a "poor man's server".

   - Are you able to have a stable, consistently **turned on** computer at the location?
   - If that computer is not able to be online all the time, can it always be on first?
3. Are you looking for advanced functionality of the printer / scanner?

   - By "advanced" I mean, things like multiple pages per sheet, or maybe stapling.
   - Sometimes those aren't always available with a network share.
4. Are you trying to avoid going through a local IT presence in your area \ business?

   - Just trying to make sure you don't create an issue for yourself.

That said, if your machines are all at least Windows 7 Professional, and you normally see each other on the network, share files and the such, you'll likely be able share the devices, with one computer acting as a "Server" and the other machines acting as a client.

**You can start trying it out on a computer that has a working printer installed, by going to:**

1. Start -> Run -> MMC (and hit Enter, or OK).

   - This will bring you to a kind of blank GUI window, likely saying "Console1 - [Console Root]" at the top.
2. Goto File -> Add/Remove Snap-In.
3. Scroll down until you see "Print Management" and click "Add", hit the button "Add the Local Server" then hit "Finish", and finally "OK".

Now the Console is populated with a Snap-In. This is one of the standard methods for Windows Administration (and being more and more moved to PowerShell and command line again, but that's another story).

If you expand the **Print Management** entry, you'll be able to see under "Custom Filters" and "All Printers" all the printers you have installed.
- Right click one of the printers, and click the **Sharing** tab.
   - Change the name to something short *and preferably, a single word, no spaces.*
   - Check off the "Share this printer" box, and for right now, ignore the warning about everyone seeing it. **HIT APPLY AT THE BOTTOM**

**Head to a co-worker's computer, and see if you see the printer when you go to the print dialog and hit "Find Printer...".**

- You'll likely have to double click on the computer on the network with your Hostname.

  - You can find your Hostname on your computer by hitting Start -> Run -> CMD.exe (hit enter).
  - Then at the prompt, typing "ipconfig /all". Your hostname will be somewhere near the top. **You are likely going to need your hostname later, write it on down!**

So if all that worked and you printed, head back to your computer, and on the same screen where you went to the **Sharing** tab, head to the **Security** tab, uncheck "Everyone" and hit Apply.

- Head to the **Security** tab, and uncheck "Everyone" and hit apply.

**If you go to to co-worker's computer, you likely can no longer see the printer, much less print to it.**

**Great, it's now "secure".** But other users can't print to it now! To resolve this, you'll need to:

1. In the same MMC Console, goto File, Add Snap In, and add one named "Local Users and Groups". Choose "Local Computer".
2. Expand the new entry on the left, then click on "Users".
3. In the black area to the right where you see the users on the account listed, right click, and hit "New User". Now for the tricky part....
4. Enter the Username as the ***EXACT SAME USERNAME AND PASSWORD*** that your co-worker uses as a login on their current machine. Come have them enter their password, once, entered, you won't be able to retrieve it, and it does NOT change the password on their computer if you change it.

   - Uncheck "User must change password at next logon, and check off "Password never expires". You'll need to go back here and have them reset their password if it ever changes on their computer.

**Whew. We're getting there!**

Head back up that console, and go find your printer under "Print Servers" and "Printers".

1. Right click, properties, and go to "Security". Hit **"Add"**, then **"Advanced"**
2. Hit "Find Now" and you'll get a list of every account on the machine. Find the one you just created, highlight by clicking on it, and then hit "OK" and "OK" again on the next screen.
3. You'll see the new user on the list of security groups or user names. Click the new user. Make sure they have at least "Print" and "Manage Documents" checked off.

Depending on how things are setup on the network, they might see the printer show back up under the network neighborhood when they find a printer. But you can have them add it locally as well.

The easiest way to do it will be by going to Start -> Run and typing something like the following:

```
\\YOURHOSTNAME\PrinterName
```

Then they should have a "local" printer that's using your workstation as a "server" (as long as it's turned on). The only people that can print to it, are people you add as a user and are an exact mimic of the user account the person is using *on their own computer* (remember, the username and password has to match exactly).

Did this mostly from memory, so I don't have screen shots for you at the moment. Let me know if you stall anywhere!